# SQL query, return rows based number of date entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres DB table that tracks quarterly event, quarterly event date, and cost.
Each event has at least 5 quarters of info, some events have 8 or more quarters.

Sample Table

`EventA | 2013-01-01 | 500
 EventA | 2013-04-01 | 600
 EventA | 2013-07-01 | 700
 EventA | 2013-10-01 | 700
 EventA | 2014-01-01 | 750
 EventB | 2013-01-01 | 400
 EventB | 2013-04-01 | 500
 EventB | 2013-07-01 | 600
 EventB | 2013-10-01 | 600
 EventB | 2014-01-01 | 575
 EventB | 2014-04-01 | 700
 EventB | 2014-07-01 | 750
 EventB | 2014-10-01 | 800
 EventB | 2015-01-01 | 800
 EventB | 2015-04-01 | 840`

I'd like to be able to do the following via a query.  If an Event has 6 or less rows, return the first quarter's row and the last.  If an Event has 7 or more quarters, return the last quarters row (latest date) and the 6th quarter back.  I.e., if an event has 3 years of information, 12 quarters, I'd like to see the 12th quarter and the 6th quarter.

I know how to use a windowing function to return a quarter count by event and use a sub query to get the results based on an event's number of quarters, i.e. less than 6 or greater than 10.  After this I'm stuck.  I'm thinking I would need to take these result sets and union them to return the rows I'm after, but don't know how to do this.

So Sample data returned from above example would be

`EventA | 2013-01-01 | 500
 EventA | 2014-01-01 | 750
 EventB | 2013-10-01 | 600
 EventB | 2015-04-10 | 840`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Missing: Postgres version, table definition, query you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table events (event text, quarter date, cost integer);
insert into events values

('EventA', '2013-01-01', 500),
('EventA', '2013-04-01', 600),
('EventA', '2013-07-01', 700),
('EventA', '2013-10-01', 700),
('EventA', '2014-01-01', 750),
('EventB', '2013-01-01', 400),
('EventB', '2013-04-01', 500),
('EventB', '2013-07-01', 600),
('EventB', '2013-10-01', 600),
('EventB', '2014-01-01', 575),
('EventB', '2014-04-01', 700),
('EventB', '2014-07-01', 750),
('EventB', '2014-10-01', 800),
('EventB', '2015-01-01', 800),
('EventB', '2015-04-01', 840);
```

Select:
- a row number in descending order and 
- a number of rows in partitions by event

and choose: 
- first row in a partition and 
- seventh or last row depending which number is less.

```
select event, quarter, cost
from (
    select 
        *, 
        row_number() over (partition by event order by quarter desc) rn,
        count(*) over (partition by event) maxn
    from events
    ) s
where rn = 1 or rn = least(maxn, 7)
order by 1, 2;

 event  |  quarter   | cost 
--------+------------+------
 EventA | 2013-01-01 |  500
 EventA | 2014-01-01 |  750
 EventB | 2013-10-01 |  600
 EventB | 2015-04-01 |  840
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you klin, I'd upvote that many times if i could.  I didn't think the solution would be so straight forward.  I had this query, but I i didn't have the where clause correct.